# How to prove the Archimedian property of natural numbers from well-ordering principle?

Tags: calculus, induction

I am going through the chapter on least upper bound of Spivak's book on calculus. He claims that the Archimedian property of the natural numbers "is not a consequence of P1-P12" (which are properties that assert the associativity and commutativity of addition and multiplication and some other stuff - from what I've heard these are basically the field axioms omitting the least upper bound property).

My question is, is it possible to prove the Archimedian property of the natural numbers using *only* the well-ordering principle, which has been established earlier without referencing the least upper bound principle. The following proof is modeled after Spivak's proof using the least upper bound and seems like a likely candidate:

Let $A$ be the set of all upper bounds of the natural numbers. Suppose $A$ is non-empty, then by the well-ordering principle there must be a smallest element $\alpha$ of $A$. Then, $\alpha \ge n$ for all $n \in N$. Consequently, $\alpha \ge n + 1$ for all $n \in N$, since $n + 1 \in N$ if $n \in N$. But this means that $\alpha -1 \ge n$ for all $n \in N$, so $\alpha - 1$ is also an upper bound for $N$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is the smallest  element of $A$.

My guess is that either (1)  the proof  above is incorrect, (2) the proof of the well-ordering  principle involves some unjustified assumptions, or (3) Spivak is deliberately ignoring the induction hypothesis in favor of demonstrating the least upper bound principle.

Comment: The well-ordering principle states "every non-empty subset of *Natural numbers* has a least element". If you consider $A$ to be the set of upper bounds of $\mathbb{N}$, how do you know that it is a subset of natural numbers? Since you are taking upper bounds in $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ contains real numbers (which may not be natural numbers) in general. So, we cannot use the well-ordering principle here.

Comment: There is another version of well-ordering "principle" which says that every set can be given a partial order such that it is well-ordered. Even if you apply this, we still don't know whether the new order in which $A$ is well-ordered is the same as that on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. (PS: If you look at the proof, it is non-constructive, i.e., it only gives the existence of such an order but does not explicitly tell us what is the order.)

Comment: Thanks Aniruddha. That makes sense.